# What does it mean for two classes have the same API but different implementations?

Tags: java, oop, object

I am a beginner to Java and object-oriented programming and having some difficulty with the concepts. For homework, I need to write two different classes that have the same exact API but are implemented differently. What does that mean and how does that work?

Comment: It's like having a car, this can be either a sportscar or a family car. They're supposed to have the same methods (accelerate, stop, start, ... ) but their behaviour is different. So, they have the same methods, just a different implementation

Answer (score 3):

I will show you.This is an example that two class have same api.

```
interface ISpeak {
    void sayHi();
}

class Teacher implements ISpeak{
    @Override
    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi!I am a Teacher!");
    }
}

class Student implements ISpeak{
    @Override
    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi!I am a Student!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the "What does it mean" question, only "How do I implement this"

Comment: @Stultuske It does illustrate it with a short example IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Same API means the two classes contain the exact same list of public methods (each having the same method name and method parameters as the other class). The implementation of these methods can be different in each class. In addition, each class can also having private methods that don't appear in the other class, since private methods are not part of the API that a class provides to its users.

An API is usually defined in Java by an interface, so two classes that have the same API will usually implement the same interface.

Comment: You're forgetting `protected` methods IINM.

Comment: @TT. I tried to give a simple answer. `protected` methods can be considered part of the API for users that extend the classes, but not part of the API for users that just create instances of the classes and don't extend them.

Comment: I always consider them part of the "programming interface". Nothing in [`API`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) makes a mention of public. Granted usually an API is said when considering an interface to the outside world, like the `interface` construct which is strictly public.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for plain language instead of "computer speak:"

An interface is like a contract. The contract may say we ***have*** to

1. Tell me your name (getName())
2. Tell me you rank  (getRank())
3. Tell me your number (getNumber())

The contract has a name (quite often ending in "able" - observable, etc.) Let's say Identifiable.
If we declare that we implement the contract we must fulfil all of its requirements.

You could be a human and I could be a robot - different classes with other different characteristics and behaviour.

```
class Human extends Object implements Identifiable
class Robot extends Object implements Identifiable
```

The program can treat us as very different objects. It can tell the robot to go and dock itself and charge. It can tell the human to do something only humans can do.  But it can ask either of them to identify themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Within Java and the wider context of modern OOP it means two `class`es should implement the same `interface`, effectively allowing clients of those classes to depend on the abstraction provided by that interface instead of the implementation details of those concrete classes.

Comment: Can you explain without using computer-speak? Explain like you would to someone who really knows nothing, in a very simple manner. Thanks.